# why the assembler does not report error on this?

Tags: assembly, integer, signed

Consider the following two statements out of a very simple assembly language program:

```
DATA1 DB  +200
DATA2 DB  -130
```

when I try to assemble it, assembler gives error on no 2 statement, as it should since a byte can hold beyond -128 decimal. But why assembler didn't give error on no 1 statement? afterall, a byte can hold max 127 positive signed integer.. instead assemlber put the value C8 in that byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any number is converted to an array of bits when it is assembled into the executable. -1, for example, is 0xFF, -2 is 0xFE, etc. The only difference between -1 and 255 is how it is used in your code. The assembler doesn't care, it just wants to store the data for you to use.

Comment: So when assigning value +200, assembler would not care about the sign bit and use the msb also as part of the bits of value 200 ?

Comment: @Saurabh - Correct, the + is not needed in that example. The MSB is not important in this case because all integers are unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it doesn't know whether or not the literal is signed or unsigned. For an assembler, I don't find that too surprising, there are use-cases for both.

-130 never fits into a byte, since it must be signed and is smaller than -128. 200, on the other hand, fits just fine into an unsigned byte, and that does seem to be the view the assembler takes, 0xC8 is 200 if interpreted as an unsigned byte.

Comment: I put the '+' sign to tell the assembler that it is a signed integer, still it didn't object to the boundary excedence. So does that mean that the onus is on the programmer to ensure that while assigning values to the variables, he should not exceed the bounds of the declared type of variables? if that is so, why this feature can't be added into the assemblers?

Comment: @Saurabh - If you want strong typing stick with a higher level language. In assembly everything is a BYTE, WORD, or DWORD. The only difference between a signed DWORD, unsigned DWORD, or HANDLE is how you use them.

Comment: To reinforce what @Sparafusile is saying.  There aren't true "signed" and "unsigned" values in assembly data statements.  "+200" is the same as "200", which is perfectly legal in a byte.  "-120" the assembler will, as a convenience turn into the appropriate value for you.  "-130" doesn't fit, so it's an error.

Comment: @Sparafusile @BrianKnoblauch so it means that whenever assembler sees '-' sign infront of an integer, it finds out its 2's complement and tries to store it the field declared by the programmer. if it fits well and good, if it doesn't, assembler generates error ??

Comment: @Saurabh - The assembler converts the number to a bit array. In your case, -130 is the same as 126 is the same as 0x7E is the same as 01111110b. That bit array is stored in the space you requested. How you use that number is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

so the gist is:

> The content of a field mean whatever you intend them to mean. The upshot of all this is that you must have a good idea as to the magnitude of the numbers that your program will process, and you must define field sizes accordinly.

Peter Abel's "IBM PC assembly language and programming".

> Also from the same author"ADD and SUB instructions do not distinguish between unsigned and signed data and, indeed, simply add and subtract bits"